# How do i set up the Android Back-Button (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, callback, back-button

So I got 2 States: a `menu-state` and a `play-state`.

If I'm in the `play-state` and click the android `back-button`, then it exits the app. But I want the `back-button` to turn me back to `menu state` instead.

How do I set that up? `OnBackPressed` is not working, because i do not have an `Activity`.

Instead I tried to set it up like this in the `play-state`:

```
@Override
public void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)){
            gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));
        }
}
```

It's kinda working, but not the way that I want it. So if I click the `back-button` now, then it goes to the `menu-state` but kinda loops between `Play-State` and `Menu-State` and then exits the app. But when I hold the `back-button` and let it go after like 3 seconds, then I'm in the K and it stays there, like i want it.

`handleInput()` is also being updated all the time.

I hope you guys could help me, since it's really important to me and I tried to fix it for hours.

I will answer questions fast.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what you mean by you do not have an Activity? What kind of Android app are you building?

Comment: A Stack of States bro

Answer (score 1):

Android activities are stored in the activity stack. If you want to go one activity back you can use something like this:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

This is going to finish your current activity and gets you back to your last activiy.

But if you already finished your last activity wich is firstactivity you need to start it again. Wich means you need to put it this way:

```
    Intent first_intent = new Intent(getApplication(), First_Activity.class);
            startActivity(first_intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Logic you want here
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Have you tried implementing `onKeyDown`? It may be part of the Activity superclass and you mentioned you're not using an Activity - what are you using?

Comment: A Stack of States, and i tried to override public boolean onKeyDown and it somehow didn't work, i think it's only available for Activities